# How do I display the data in belongs_to model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to display "code" in comments model on "_article.html.erb". How should I modify following sources?

.schema articles

```
CREATE TABLE "articles" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    "content" varchar(255), 
    "user_id" integer, 
    "comment_id" integer,
    "created_at" datetime, 
    "updated_at" datetime);
```

.schema comments

```
CREATE TABLE "comments" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    "code" integer, 
    "created_at" datetime, 
    "updated_at" datetime);
```

article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :comment
end
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles
end
```

users/show.html.erb

```
    <%= render @articles %>
```

articles/_article.html.erb

```
<li>
    <%= article.comment.code %>
    <span class="content"><%= article.content %></span>
    by <%= article.user.name %>
</li>
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @articles = @user.articles.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

The following error appears on my screen after adding `<%= article.comment.code %>` in articles/_article.html.erb.

**NoMethodError in Users#show**

Showing e:/....../app/views/articles/_article.html.erb where line #2 raised:
undefined method `code' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #2):

```
1 <li>
2    <%= article.comment.code %>
3    <span class="content"><%= article.content %></span>
4    by <%= article.user.name %>
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/users/show.html.erb

app/views/articles/_article.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_articles__article_html_erb__849237918_32363016'

app/views/users/show.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__1073019711_34316652'

Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"1"}

And Full Trace is as follows;

```
app/views/articles/_article.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_articles__article_html_erb__849237918_32363016'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:399:in `block in collection_with_template'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:395:in `map'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:395:in `collection_with_template'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:291:in `render_collection'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:275:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:274:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
app/views/users/show.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__1073019711_34316652'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:433:in `_run__756630078__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:674:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.4)  lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:373:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__522467988__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.4) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: `<%= article.comment.code %>` will do the trick.

Comment: Did that worked for you?

Comment: I added `<%= article.comment.code %>` in articles/_article.html.erb but NoMethodError in Users#show appeared. Why do this message arise?

Comment: Can you post the exact error with the stacktrace in the question?

Comment: Pavan, I updated Full Trace. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems comment.code is nil for that particular articular.May be try giving like this `<%= article.comment.code  if comment != nil%>`

Comment: I added `<%= article.comment.code  if comment != nil %>` but it doesn't work. NameError in Stocks#show and Undefined local variable or method `comment' for #<#<Class:0x5c82408>:0x608c7d8>

Comment: OK,try this `<%= article.comment.code  if article.comment != nil %>`

Comment: Thanks to all of you, it works after checking data integrity without adding above code.

Comment: Glad to help and Please accept one the answers by ticking the tick mark green :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **`relation`** between **`Article`** and **`Comment`** like this

```
<%= article.comment.code %>
```

to get the **`code`** of **`comment`** for the **`associated article`**.

The better way would be adding a **`delegate`**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :comment

    delegate :code, to: 'comment', allow_nil: true
end
```

By doing so,you can simply call it as

```
<%= article.code%>
```

For more info,see this **[API](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate)**

Answer (score 2):

[**foreign_keys**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)

Further to `Pavan`'s answer, you'll be best understanding *how* ActiveRecord Associations work:

```
#app/models/comment.rb
Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :article
   belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/article.rb
Class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments
end
```

This basically sets up a relational database connection, which will use [`foreign_keys`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) to pull associative data on `ActiveRecord` objects:

```
#comments
id | user_id | article_id | message | created_at | updated_at

#articles
id | user_id | title | message | created_at | updated_at
```

--

**Setup**

I don't know why you've got `article` belongs_to `comment` - I presume the opposite would be true?

I would definitely look at how you want your ActiveRecord structure to work - the standard `has_many` association is pretty standard:

[image]

I'd personally set up the association like I described above, which will allow you to do the following:

```
@article = Article.find params[:id]
@article.comments.each do |comment|
   comment.code
end
```

Comment: Rich Peck, Thank you for your advice, and I apologize for the confusion. But in my model, `article` belongs_to `comment` and `comment` has_many `article` is correct. It's not like a blog. I would appreciate any other advice regarding this issue.